# How to force the DynamoDB query's ExclusiveStartKey to use exact match?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB for my new Serverless Restful API with nodejs.

The Restful API supports query for resources with the `limit` and `lastKey` query parameters for key pagination.

Assume there's a table like below:

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| School | firstSchool |
| School | secondSchool |
| School | thirdSchool |

`PK` is partition key, and `SK` is sort key.
I use `SK` for key pagination.

If I call the api with `http://somewhere/api/school?limit=1&lastKey=secondSchool`, `ExclusiveStartKey` in query will be `{"PK" : "School", "SK" : "secondSchool"}`, and the returned item will be `{"PK" : "School", "SK" : "thirdSchool"}`.

It works well in that case, but the problem is the same result is created with the url like `http://somewhere/api/school?limit=1&lastKey=seco`.
In this case, `ExclusiveStartKey` in query will be `{"PK" : "School", "SK" : "seco"}`

It seems DynamoDB doesn't use exact match for a sk value in `ExclusiveStartKey`.

Is there any way to force DynamoDB to use exact match for `ExclusiveStartKey`?

I attach my test code below:

```js
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocument } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");


const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: AWS_REGION,
  endpoint: AWS_DYNAMODB_END_POINT,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESSKEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});

const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocument.from(ddbClient);


(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await ddbDocClient.query({
      TableName: "Table Name",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#pk = :pk",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#pk": "PK",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":pk": "Test",
      },
      Limit: 1,
      ExclusiveStartKey: { PK: "Test", SK: "Seco" },
    });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Are you using the last evaluated key returned in the previous request? The exclusive start key should be using the value that was returned for `LastEvaluatedKey` in the previous operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ExclusiveKeyStart` is used mainly for **paging** large `Scan` or `Query` requests - i.e., retrieving the next page of results after the previous page ended with a `LastEvaluatedKey`, and you are supposed to give **exactly** that key (not some subset of it...) as the `ExclusiveKeyStart` of the next request.

You are trying to do something different, and to achieve you can't use `ExclusiveKeyStart`, but you can use something else:

The [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) request has a `KeyConditionExpression`. You can specify `sk > :value` as a key condition expression (don't pass ExclusiveKeyStart), and you'll get this all the sort keys higher than that `:value` like your string "seco". Please note, however, that because your sort key is truncated, this result may actually include one or more extra results before the first key you want (e.g., the keys "seco" and "secoaaaa" come before "secondSchool") so you may need to drop them yourself from the results.

The `KeyConditionExpression` is implemented efficiently - DynamoDB knows how to skip directly to that sort key in the partition, and doesn't charge you for reading the entire partition, so in this respect it is just as good as `ExclusiveKeyStart`.

Comment: As far as I understand, the Query/Scan can return the data up to 1MB at once, so LastEvaluatedKey/ExclusiveStartKey is for that scenario(such as scanning entire partition). And KeyConditionExpression is more suitable for my plot, isn't it?

Comment: Query/Scan can return the data up to 1MB, but if you explicitly specify a "Limit" it will return earlier - after this number of items were read from disk (it can return fewer items if there is also a FilterExpression involved).  I'm not sure how this detail is relevant to your original question, though.